# Creating certificate issued based on self-signed root certificate with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle

I have been using [this repo](https://github.com/rlipscombe/bouncy-castle-csharp/blob/master/CreateCertificate/Program.cs) that allows creating a certificate based on self-signed Root Certificate.

My Root Certificate was given to me in the form of MyCARoot.cer and MyCARoot.pvk They were created (and already deployed) previously with makecert. So in order for me to use the code in the above link I had to combine .cer and .pvk files in .pfx using pvk2pfx.exe

My problem is that after generating the certificate and importing it to Personal store it seems to be invalid. On the Certification Path tab in MMC it says:

> The issuer of the certificate could not be found

Note: the only change I made to the code are the password that were used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that source was that it was supposed to do this:

```
X509Certificate issueCert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(issuerCertificate);
var authorityKeyIdentifier = new AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(issueCert);
certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.Id, false, authorityKeyIdentifier);
```

instead of this:

```
var authorityKeyIdentifierExtension =
new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(
    SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(issuerKeyPair.Public),
    new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(issuerDN)),
    issuerSerialNumber);

certificateGenerator.AddExtension(
    X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.Id, false, authorityKeyIdentifierExtension);
```